# Error [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] when working with enum

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

My android app has enum class Specialization:

```
enum class Specialization {
    DEVELOPER, MANAGER
}
```

The values of this class are passed to the viewmodel, which makes a request to the repository based on this:

```
class EmployeesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val typeSpecialization: Specialization,
    private val getEmployeesListUseCase: GetEmployeesListUseCase
): ViewModel() {

    val screenState: Flow<EmployeesFragmentScreenState> = getEmployeesListUseCase(typeSpecialization)
        .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
        .map { EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Content(employees = it) as EmployeesFragmentScreenState }
        .onStart { emit(EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Loading) }

}
```

RecycleView:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: SpecializationItemViewHolder,
        position: Int
    ) {
        val specItem = getItem(position)
        val binding = holder.binding

        binding.specializationName.text = specItem.specializationName
        binding.idspec.text = specItem.specialty_id.toString()

        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            onSpecializationClickListener?.invoke(specItem.specialty_id)
        }

    }
```

SpecializationListFragment:

```
class SpecializationListFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentSpecializationListBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentSpecializationListBinding
        get() = _binding ?: throw RuntimeException("FragmentSpecializationListBinding is null")

    private lateinit var specializationListAdapter: SpecializationListAdapter

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory

    private val component by lazy{
        (requireActivity().application as CoreApplication).component
    }

    lateinit var viewModel: SpecializationViewModel

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        component.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentSpecializationListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)[SpecializationViewModel::class.java]
        setupRecyclerView()
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED){
                viewModel.screenState.collect{
                    when(it){
                        is SpecializationsFragmentScreenState.Content -> {
                            //Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Spec Content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            binding.progressSpecLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                            specializationListAdapter.submitList(it.specializations)
                        }
                        is SpecializationsFragmentScreenState.Loading -> {
                            binding.progressSpecLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView(){
        with(binding.rvSpList){
            specializationListAdapter = SpecializationListAdapter()
            adapter = specializationListAdapter
        }
        setupClickListener()
    }

    private fun setupClickListener(){
        specializationListAdapter.onSpecializationClickListener = {
            launchEmployeesListFragment(it)
        }
    }

    private fun launchEmployeesListFragment(typeSpecialization: Int){
        val type = if(typeSpecialization == 101){
            Specialization.MANAGER
        }else{
            Specialization.DEVELOPER
        }
        findNavController().navigate(SpecializationListFragmentDirections.actionSpecializationListFragmentToEmployeesListFragment(type))
    }

}
```

EmployeesListFragment:

```
class EmployeesListFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentEmployeesListBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentEmployeesListBinding
        get() = _binding ?: throw RuntimeException("FragmentEmployeesListBinding is null")

    private val args by navArgs<EmployeesListFragmentArgs>()


    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactoryD: ViewModelFactory

    private val component by lazy{
        (requireActivity().application as CoreApplication).component
    }

    lateinit var viewModel: EmployeesViewModel

    private lateinit var employeeListAdapter: EmployeesListAdapter

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        component.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentEmployeesListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactoryD)[EmployeesViewModel::class.java]

        setupRecyclerView()

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED){
                viewModel.screenState.collect{
                    when(it){
                        is EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Content ->{
                            binding.progressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                            employeeListAdapter.submitList(it.employees)
                        }
                        is EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Loading ->{
                            binding.progressLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


    private fun setupRecyclerView(){
        with(binding.rvEmpList){
            employeeListAdapter = EmployeesListAdapter()
            adapter = employeeListAdapter
        }
        setupClickListener()
    }

    private fun setupClickListener(){
        employeeListAdapter.onEmployeeClickListener = {
            launchEmployeeFragment(it)
        }
    }

    private fun launchEmployeeFragment(employee: Employee){
        findNavController().navigate(EmployeesListFragmentDirections.actionEmployeesListFragmentToEmployeeFragment(employee))
    }

}
```

Next, I just get the specialty type on the next screen and pass it to the ViewModel, which makes a request to the repository via UseCase. Depending on the type, employees of a certain specialty will be received.

How to handle this situation with Dagger 2? When trying to write a method for provides, the error [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] naturally occurs:

```
@Module
class DomainModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSpecializationDeveloper(): Specialization {
        return Specialization.DEVELOPER
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideSpecializationManager(): Specialization {
        return Specialization.MANAGER
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the view model in the Fragment? (How you are requesting the view model)

Comment: Added fragment classes. With SpecializationListFragment, the transition to EmployeesListFragment is performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you were actually asking is how to pass the navigation argument to the view model of another fragment.

What you want is [SavedStateHandle API](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-savedstate) + [Navigation Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/safe-args).

```
class EmployeesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val getEmployeesListUseCase: GetEmployeesListUseCase
): ViewModel() {

    val typeSpecialization: Specialization = EmployeesListFragmentArgs.fromSavedStateHandle(savedStateHandle)).type

    val screenState: Flow<EmployeesFragmentScreenState> = getEmployeesListUseCase(typeSpecialization)
        .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
        .map { EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Content(employees = it) as EmployeesFragmentScreenState }
        .onStart { emit(EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Loading) }
}
```

You might have some issues passing the enum direcly - I would just pass the Int and map it in view model to safe the hassle - if you want to go that route - [here is how](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/pass-data#use_keep_annotations).

```
val type = if (typeSpecialization == 101) {
    Specialization.MANAGER
} else {
    Specialization.DEVELOPER
}
```

But in order to do this you will have to update your `ViewModelFactory` to [SavedStateViewModelFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateViewModelFactory)

I know it is a lot of changes to here is something that will work with minimal changes:

```
class EmployeesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getEmployeesListUseCase: GetEmployeesListUseCase
): ViewModel() {

    var isInitalized: Boolean = false
    
    private _screenState: MutableStateFlow<EmployeesFragmentScreenState> = MutableStateFlow(EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Loading)
    val screenState: StateFlow<EmployeesFragmentScreenState> = _screenState.asStateFlow()

    fun initialize(typeSpecialization: Specialization) {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            isInitialized = true
            viewModelScope.launch {
                getEmployeesListUseCase(typeSpecialization)
                    .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
                    .map { EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Content(employees = it) as EmployeesFragmentScreenState }
                    .collect { newState ->
                        _screenState.update { newState }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactoryD)[EmployeesViewModel::class.java]
    viewModel.initialize(arguments?.getInt("type")) //where "type" is the name of the argument in navGraph
    setupRecyclerView()

    viewModel.screenState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle {
        when(it) {
            is EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Content ->{
                binding.progressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                employeeListAdapter.submitList(it.employees)
            }
            is EmployeesFragmentScreenState.Loading ->{
                binding.progressLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But the parameter in the EmployeesViewModel constructor is now clearly marked with the @DeveloperSpecialization annotation and the DEVELOPER value always gets there. According to the logic of the program, depending on the user's choice, either MANAGER or DEVELOPER comes there. So I couldn't figure out how to handle this situation and whether it's possible.

Comment: @MetalGear Yeah, I sort of guessed that but I wasn't sure it was the question and since your original logic ignored any user input I assumed it wasn't. Where do you store the decision of which specialization the user wants?

Comment: My application has a list of specialties and when you click on a certain specialty, a new screen opens with a list of employees. When you click on an element in the RecyclerView, it turns out which type of specialty to pass to the next screen in the ViewModel for display. I have updated the blocks with the code in the question and maybe it has become clearer now.

Comment: @MetalGear I updated the answer to match what you were actually asking.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for your help!